# Layout messed up in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a simple web page for experiment:
Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <!-- <div class="navbar-header"></div> -->
                    <center>Menu Bar!</center>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="./imgs/index.jpeg" alt="Chania">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="./imgs/index1.jpeg" alt="Chania">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="./imgs/index2.jpeg" alt="Flower">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="./imgs/index3.jpeg" alt="Flower">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="well"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="well"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="well"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="well"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="footer">
            <nav class="container">
                Footer!!
            </nav>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the web page is like this:
[image: img]
Footer isn't coming up properly. Carousel isn't working properly. But the page is responsive and loads properly in various screens. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your images are something that can be found. By appearance alone it seems that your code was able to find index.jpeg but not any of the others. Try using index.jpeg all 4 times and see if that helps.

```
<div class="item active">
    <img src="./imgs/index.jpeg" alt="Chania">
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="./imgs/index.jpeg" alt="Chania">
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="./imgs/index.jpeg" alt="Flower">
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="./imgs/index.jpeg" alt="Flower">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it. Access to other image files was restricted because those were in `/var/www/html/myproject/imgs`. I added access permissions and it worked :)